# Mac absolute time from Hex

Tags: python, timestamp, hex

I'm trying to convert a time stamp from an iPhone database that's stored in Hex as part of a Python script.

I have searched online and been unable to find how it's done.

An example of the time stamps:
`41 C4 C2 FA 5E 8C E8 64` which is equal to 29/01/2023 00:26:37 (UTC).
I know this as a couple of tools such as deCode are able to convert it, but now "workings out" are shown.

Thanks

As stated I been unable to find the actual method of converting the hex into a readable time. Multiple tools are able to convert it, just not as part of the script

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please post **what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems**. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: That's a double-precision floating point number, stored in big-endian form. 
 696644797.100842.  It's the number of seconds since 1/1/2001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is a big-endian representation of a double-precision floating point number representing the number of seconds since 1/1/2001.  So:

```
import time
import datetime
import struct

x = "41 C4 C2 FA 5E 8C E8 64"
z = bytes([int(x1,16) for x1 in x.split()])
p = struct.unpack('>d',z)[0]
print(p)

d = datetime.datetime(2001,1,1,0,0,0)
d = d.timestamp()+p
print(time.ctime(d))
```

Output:

```
696644797.100842
Sun Jan 29 00:26:37 2023
```